# java.io.IOException: java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Malformed input or input contains unmappable characters

Tags: java, linux, jenkins, centos7

I want to run Ruby tests on Jenkins server. But for some reason I get this error in log file:

```
java.io.IOException: java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Malformed input or input contains unmappable characters: /home/jenkins/.jenkins/workspace/web_payment_ghe_ws-cleanup_1482248748134/web_payment/.git/refs/remotes/origin/feature/b2016112202-��xpiration-date-on-wpf-form
```

I'm using Jenkins with Centos 7. It looks like I need to install language pack support but I'm not sure which package I need to install. Can you give some idea?